# How to choose middleware paradigm

Tags: java, osgi, ejb-3.0, apache-camel, middleware

I've been reading up on Java middleware solutions, and unless I've gone completely off-base here (which I may have done, **in which case please start by correcting me!**), it seems that there are four major middleware solutions/paradigms you can choose for an enterprise application:

- Fully-compliant Java EE (EJB3s); or
- 3rd Party ESB like Apache Camel or Mule; or
- OSGi; or
- Event-Driven Architectures

I'm looking for something of a rubric, or a protocol to follow that will allow me to say:

> Given business needs xyz, the best middleware strategy for this app is xyz.

I guess I'm wondering what pros/cons/strengths/caveats each of these four have and how those attributes fit into the decision-making behind which of these 4 avenues to go down.

Can someone please provide real-life use cases for when each of these 4 would be preferable over the alternatives? Maybe from those use cases we can extract such a rubric.

Comment: Pretty sure this qualifies and chatty and open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a 5th answer is: "a 3rd party communications middleware, like DDS, CORBA, or JMS".  These are all standardized technologies for inter-process data communications.

I personally like DDS ([Data Distribution Service](http://portals.omg.org/dds/)) for it's performance (< 100 usec latencies on local networks), flexibility (dynamic discovery of endpoints means there are no server look-ups), and powerful data storage, presentation, and filtering options.  DDS supports Java (in addition to other languages) and is used for enterprise applications in multiple domains (financial, medial, DoD, just to name a few).

Answer (score 0):

A good 3rd party EIS architecture can incorporate the other three options so one would be remiss not recommending it ....